# Python always prints first statement ignoring elifs

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

It's my first app as well as first StackOverflow post. Glad that you're there!

My issue is that my app is ignoring elifs, and assuming that first IF is always right.

```
print("Gimme unit ID" )
unitid = input()
unitid = int(unitid)
service = ""
if unitid>= 100:
    service= "SuperOne"
elif unitid>= 10000:
    service= "Suprer10K"
elif unitid>= 30000:
    service= "Amazing30K"
elif unitid>= 40000:
    service= "SuperAsom40k"
elif unitid>= 50000:
    service= "SuperAmazing60k"
elif unitid>= 70000:
    service= "New"
else:
    print("Please validate unit id.")
print(f"Your service is called {service}")
```

It's always printing "Your service is called SuperOne", even if you write 35000 or something.

Could you help?

Answer (score 2):

You should write ifs in descending order. For example:

```
if unitid >= 70000:
elif  unitid >= 60000:
```

and so on.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Reverse order of `if`.

Something bigger than 40000 is also bigger than 100 so first match will be used.

```
if unitid>= 70000:
   service= "New"
elif unitid>= 50000:
   service= "SuperAmazing60k"
elif unitid>= 40000:
    service= "SuperAsom40k"
...
```